# Exit() is not working for d3 group bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have created a group bar chart with json data.on click on legend I want to show and hide particular bar from group in chart (using enter and exit functionality of d3).

My json data is like this

```
var values = [{
    "timeId": "201501040100",
    "value": 2454721,
    "week": 1
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040100",
    "value": 4017731,
    "week": 2
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040100",
    "value": 6656528,
    "week": 3
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040100",
    "value": 7472223,
    "week": 4
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040200",
    "value": 2454721,
    "week": 1
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040200",
    "value": 3017731,
    "week": 2
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040200",
    "value": 5017731,
    "week": 3
}, {
    "timeId": "201501040200",
    "value": 7472223,
    "week": 4
}, ];
```

I have grouped this data based on timeId

```
weeksVolume = _.groupBy(values, 'timeId');
weeksVolume = Object.keys(weeksVolume).map(function(key) {
    return weeksVolume[key]
});
```

Working Plunkr solution is here https://plnkr.co/edit/sUy564JZfAoKDb24U5VA?p=preview

now click on first legend I want to hide and show "week : 1" data from each click.for that on click on legend I have handle the modification of data(means removing or adding of particular week data from dataset.

With the updated dataset I tried to reDraw the chart but it is not working properly.every time it is removing and adding data from last index.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `updateChart` function:

```
function updateChart() {

    ...

    volumeBars = week.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d, i) {
            return d;
        });  // <= Here is the problem

   ...
}
```

You have to define a way to make unique each element, in order to find them easily. You have to attribute a key, and d3 selections will use it to know if a element is new / already present / removed from the current selection. The 2nd argument of `data` function makes that:

```
volumeBars = week.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d, i) {
        return d;
    },
    function(d){return d.timeId + d.week;});
    //Here you can define the key you want
```

You can find the documentation for `data` function here: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#data

In addition, you don't have to create another selection before your `exit`  call. Selection is already created before, the same on which you called your `enter`. So you can just write:

```
volumeBars.exit().text(function(d) {console.log(d);}).remove();
```

Here the update plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/inrD7aC3KYmv8iU2gnkA?p=preview

Hope it helps.