# D3 exit() not functioning as expected in grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble understanding how the `exit()` selection works in my grouped bar chart. My example has only empty `exit()` selections, and thus nothing is removed from the chart when it's updated.

This is similar to the problem posted here: [d3 grouped bar chart update pattern not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201314/d3-grouped-bar-chart-update-pattern-not-working). But since I append an `'g'` to the `chartArea` object I don't think the solution is applicable.

I am loosely following the grouped/stacked bar chart example from here: https://bl.ocks.org/aholachek/fb0c1cd7ea9707bc8ff55a82402c54b1

The full jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fg_ti/ka306sjc/68/ and the code:

```
var data1 = [
  {
    "sex": "female",
    "n_patients": 5,
    "grouping":"A"
  },
  {
    "sex": "male",
    "n_patients": 10,
    "grouping": "A"
  },
  {
    "sex": "female",
    "n_patients": 25,
    "grouping":"B"
  },
  {
    "sex": "male",
    "n_patients": 10,
    "grouping":"B"
  }];
var data2 = [
  {
    "sex": "female",
    "n_patients": 62,
    "grouping":"A"
  },
  {
    "sex": "male",
    "n_patients": 55,
    "grouping":"A"
  },
  {
    "sex": "female",
    "n_patients": 25,
    "grouping": "B"
  },
  {
    "sex": "male",
    "n_patients": 83,
    "grouping":"B"
  },
  {
   "sex": "female",
   "n_patients": 25,
   "grouping": "D"},
  {
    "sex": "male",
    "n_patients": 83,
    "grouping": "D"
   }];

width = 350;
height = 450;

var initData = d3.nest().key(d => d.grouping).entries(data1)
var margin = ({top:10, right:10, bottom:10, left:30});
var Gwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
var Gheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom
var barPadding = 0.1;

var colors = ['#ffe1e1', '#d1ecfd']
svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
var topG = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top +')')


// Initial scale

// Scale between the keys (i.e. b/w age groups, edu, etc`)
var scaleX = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(initData.map(d => d.key))
  .range([0, Gwidth])
  .padding(barPadding);

var scaleColors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(colors)

// Initial axis
var yAxis = topG.append('g')
  .attr("class", "y axis")

var xAxis = topG.append('g')
    .attr("class", "x axis")

xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(scaleX))
    .attr("transform", 'translate(' + 0 + "," + Gheight + ')');

var chartArea = topG.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chartArea");



// UPDATE FUNCTION - will be called by r2d3.onRender()
function update(inData) {

  // Reshape data
  var newData = d3.nest()
    .key(d => d.grouping)
    .entries(inData);


  var maxY = d3.max(newData, d => d3.max(d.values, k => k.n_patients));
  grouping1Names = newData.map(d => d.key);
  grouping2Names = newData[0].values.map(d => d.sex);
  var t = 1000;

  // Scales used in updates 
  var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, maxY])
    .range([Gheight, 0]);

  var scaleX = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(grouping1Names)
    .range([0, Gwidth])
    .padding(barPadding);

  var scaleX1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(grouping2Names)
    .rangeRound([0, scaleX.bandwidth()]);


  // Perform the data join

   var barGroupWithData = chartArea
      .selectAll('.barGroup')
      .data(newData);

    barGroupWithData.exit().remove();

   // Join rect elements with data - specified with keys
   var bars = barGroupWithData.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + scaleX(d.key) + ",0)")
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .merge(barGroupWithData)
      .selectAll("rect")
          .data(d => Object.keys(d.values)
                          .map(k => ({ keyL2: grouping2Names[k], value: d.values[k].n_patients }) ));



  console.log(bars)

  // Remove rect elements joined with data that is no longer present
  bars.exit().remove()

  bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", d => scaleColors(d.keyL2))
    .attr("y", d => scaleY(0))
    .merge(bars)
    .attr("x", (d) => scaleX1(d.keyL2))
    .attr("width", scaleX1.bandwidth())
    .transition()
    .duration(t)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr('y', d => scaleY(d.value))
    .attr("height", d => scaleY(0) - scaleY(d.value));

  console.log(bars)

  // Udpate axes
  yAxis.transition()
    .duration(t)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(scaleY))

  xAxis.transition()
    .duration(t)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(scaleX))

}

//


update(data1);

 // Update the data
  setInterval(function (newDat) {

            if(Math.random()>0.5) {
            d = data1
            } else {
            d = data2
            }


            return update(d);
        }, 3000);
```

I suspect I am not joining the data correctly, but cannot pinpoint where this goes wrong. The first posted answer to this questions seems close, but does not work for my solution: [Exit() is not working for d3 group bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420239/exit-is-not-working-for-d3-group-bar-chart).

Any advice to properly removing the old data from the chart?

==================== EDIT =============

To clarify, I modified the data to highlight the problem better ([updated jsfidlde](https://jsfiddle.net/fg_ti/ka306sjc/83/)). The data seems to join to the `rect` elements fine - with each update, new bars are appended. However the old `rect` elements are not removed. 
Since the keys for joining data to the `rect`s are specified as such:

```
(.data(d => Object.keys(d.values)
                              .map(k => ({ keyL2: grouping2Names[k], value: d.values[k].n_patients }) ));` `.enter()`
```

I therefore expected the `.data()` to match the incoming data against the data in the existing `rect` elements. **If incoming data has different values for `n_patients` or `grouping`, I would think d3 would recognize the new data as "entering" and append, and conversely, already existing data whose `n_patient` or `grouping` values are not matched with the new data as "exiting" and remove.** This is based on the responses to this question: [D3 Key Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175624/d3-key-function); and an [old blog post](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) from Mike Bostock

Since new `rect`s are appended in each `.enter()` call, it seems d3 is recognizing the "entering" data, but not recognizing the "exiting" data in the way I have written my code. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Both your data sets have the same number of entries for each groups, so the bars/scale will just transition to the new domain but bars won't be added or removed.

Comment: have a look at your svg DOM with DevTools. There is something wrong in your code. Or is the chart animating what you want?

Comment: @pmkro thanks, I edited the post to better highlight the issue. Since the data join is keyed (i.e. not keyed on index), even if the number of elements are the same, changes should be entered and exited, right?

Comment: @rioV8, thanks, from examining the svg I can see new elements are joined and append, but none are removed. The new jsfiddle better highlights the issue

Comment: read the docs (d3-select) about `select(All)` and the Data join