# Updating grouped bar charts does not clear existing charts

Tags: node.js, d3.js

When updating a grouped bar chart, the previous chart does not disappear. I don't know what's wrong.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396369/d3-exit-not-functioning-as-expected-in-grouped-bar-chart?noredirect=1&lq=1
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fg_ti/ka306sjc/68/

When I searched, this error is exactly the same as my symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data join is looking for anything with a class ".barGroup", but when you create the g elements, you don't assign a class.  So D3 doesn't find a match when it does the join with new data, so appends new elements.

Update this part of the code:

```
var bars = barGroupWithData.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr('class', 'barGroup') //add this class to new g elements, and now D3 will find it on subsequent data joins
```

https://jsfiddle.net/35r0owt7/

Comment: I love you so thank you very much :)

I want to give a recommendation but I don't know how. :(

Comment: thanks - accepting the answer will suffice :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers